# Safely host PHP websites on Windows

Tags: php, web-hosting

I would like to host a few 3rd party PHP scripts on a Windows server (running in VMware), so I am looking for a way to limit all the users to accessing their own directories (and subdirectories) and prevent them from executing anything on the machine.

Port 25 is completely blocked and there is a very low limit on the number of external connections they are allowed to make.

There must be others that have come across this issue and any ideas, advice and tips are welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: if running vmware already, why not run some variety of *nix?

Comment: I have some things that need to run on the same computer and they're only available on Windows. Long story short, I have to stick to Windows.

Comment: After not getting an answer I wanted, I just set up a lot of virtual machines. Everything went smoothly. Later, I put Apache in a chroot jail as @Pekka suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PHP, there's the `open_basedir` restriction that is supposed to limit PHP script access to certain directories, and it usually does. However, it seems to be flawed. Article [**here**](http://blog.php-security.org/archives/72-Open_basedir-confusion.html) - It's from 2008 though, so the shortcomings described there may have been already addressed in a recent release.

There's also the much hated [safe mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) that may have its place until PHP 6 comes along (it will be removed there.) be very careful with allowing scripts to execute outside binaries.

[**Suhosin**](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) adds additional security and restriction possibilities to PHP and is certainly a good idea to install. Its defaults may interfere with more complex apps, so be sure to look deeply into its config file. However, it looks like you have to recompile PHP to get it running on Windows. This is something I would really recommend looking into.

If you need something stronger and can use Linux, putting [Apache in a chroot jail](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap29sec254.html) is something I came across a few days ago. It looks totally advanced, though.